# Django Autocomplete-light Case Sensitivity Issue

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have created a basic setup for autocomplete-light on one of my forms. I am using direct SQL queries to access the data I require, and the Select2ListView to send the data to the template. The autocomplete data is available on the browser, but it is **case sensitive**. Can someone please suggest what I can do to make the autocomplete-light become case **in**sensitive?

I read about using 'split_words = True' from the AutocompleteModel class, but I have no idea how to do this.

For example (q = 'ger'):

Command Prompt (views.py print statement) returns

> ['Algeria', '**Germany**', 'Niger (the), 'Nigeria']

http://127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete/country-autocomplete?q=ger returns

> {"results": [{"text": "Algeria", "id": "Algeria"}, {"text": "Niger (the)", "id": "Niger (the)"}, {"text": "Nigeria", "id": "Nigeria"}]}

As you can see,  Germany is visible in the data I am returning from the view, but there is some additional filtering going on by autocomplete-light. I need to change autocomplete-light so that the filtering it performs is case-insensitive. Any ideas?

I am running Python 3.5.2, and the latest pip install for autocomplete-light.

Thanks
Stephen

**View**

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2ListView):
    def get_list(self):
    # Only allow authenticated users
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return []

    # Read all country names from database
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT country_name FROM autocomplete_iso3166;')
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    # Flatten database query into a list
    results = [e for l in results for e in l]

    # Check POST query and filter further
    if self.q:
        # Make query case insensitive
        results = list(filter(lambda k: self.q.casefold() in str(k).casefold(), results))

    print(results)
    return results
```

**Form**

```
    class VendorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = client
        fields = [
            'vendor_name', 'address5', 'address4', 'address3', 'address2', 'address1',

            ]


    widgets = {
    'address5': autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='country-autocomplete'),
    'address4': autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='state-autocomplete',forward=['address5'])
    }
```

**Model**

```
class client(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    address3 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    address4 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    address5 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.q:
    queryset = queryset.filter(country_name__istartswith=self.q)
```

i means case insensitive.  This example uses the beginning of the field.

If you want an exact match case-insensitive it would be:

```
country_name__iexact=self.q
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate that using a queryset may allow case insensitivity, but I prefer to use the raw SQL function, and that doesn't seem to integrate properly with autocomplete-light. I have since disabled Django autocomplete light and I am currently using "Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery".